# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 "CScanner::CScanner(void*)", referenced from

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, undefined-symbol

I have looked into these kind of errors on posts but most of them have an _OBJC_CLASS name that you could track down. This error looks different.

```
-(void) initLocal
{
    m_pScanner = new CScanner(self);
}
```

and the class looks like:

```
class CScanner : public SmartcodeDecoder::Observer {
public:
    CScanner(void* pControler);
};
```

The error looks like the following image:
[image]

Comment: Check your project architectures. You probably want to build for an iOS, but your target is set to Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The linker can't find the definition of function `CScanner::CScanner(void*)`. The code above shows a declaration of that function, but not its implementation. Find the source code file or library that implements that function, and make sure it is added to the project.

As Eugene noted, the linker warning about mismatched architectures is suspicious. It's possible that the implementation of `CScanner::CScanner(void*)` is present for some architectures but not for i386 (which is the one you're trying to build).

Comment: Probably a library that doesn't support the iOS simulator